# asyncio.StreamReader блокирует программу

Tags: python, tcp-ip, asyncio

Есть некий удалённый API, который поддерживает соединение через TCP/IP. Он принимает команды в виде строгой последовательности байт и в случае успеха почти сразу возвращает ответ. Плюс раз в секунду шлёт keepalive. Ниже приведена часть программы, которую я написал на Python3.7 для отправки и приёма команд.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from queue import Queue, Empty
import asyncio
import time

tasks_queue: Queue = Queue()        # Очередь задач на отправку
cancellation_token: bool = False


class Task:

    def __init__(self, local_time: datetime, command: str, status: str):
        self.local_time = local_time
        self.command = command
        self.status = status


async def tcp_client():
    global cancellation_token
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 50007)
    while not cancellation_token:
        try:
            task_for_send = tasks_queue.get_nowait()
            writer.write(task_for_send.command.encode())
        except Empty:
            pass
        while True:
            if not len(reader._buffer):
                await asyncio.sleep(0)
                break
            try:
                data = await reader.read(10)
            except ConnectionResetError:
                cancellation_token = True
                break
            print(f'Received: {data.decode()!r}')
            if not len(reader._buffer):
                await asyncio.sleep(0)
                break
            if not data:
                break

    print('Close the connection')
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    print('Connection is closed')


async def generate_one_task_per_second():
    global cancellation_token
    while not cancellation_token:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        tasks_queue.put(Task(datetime.now(), 'F700560D0A', 'new'))


async def main():
    print(f"started at {time.strftime('%X')}")
    await asyncio.gather(
        generate_one_task_per_second(),
        tcp_client(),
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Когда asyncio.StreamReader (`data = await reader.read(10)`) опустошает буфер полностью, он блокирует выполнение программы.
Приходится использовать следующую конструкцию для проверки наличия в буфере чего-либо:

```py
    if not len(reader._buffer):
        await asyncio.sleep(0)
        break
```

Т.е. `if not data: break` уже не выполнится.

Подскажите, как более правильно выйти из данной ситуации? Может как-то можно установить таймаут на чтение или вообще разделить reader и writer на две асинхронные таски?

На всякий случай  выкладываю сервер-заглушку:

```py
import socket
import sys
from time import sleep

HOST = '127.0.0.1'       # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 50007             # Arbitrary non-privileged port
s = None
for res in socket.getaddrinfo(HOST, PORT, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM,
                              0, socket.AI_PASSIVE):
    af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
    try:
        s = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)
    except OSError as msg:
        s = None
        continue
    try:
        s.bind(sa)
        s.listen(1)
        print(f'Listen host: {HOST}, port: {PORT}')
    except OSError as msg:
        s.close()
        s = None
        continue
    break
if s is None:
    print('could not open socket')
    sys.exit(1)
while True:
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    with conn:
        print('Connected by', addr)
        while True:
            try:
                data = conn.recv(10)
                if not data:
                    sleep(0.1)
                    continue
                print(data)
                conn.send(data)
            except (ConnectionResetError, ConnectionAbortedError):
                print('Disconnected by', addr)
                break
```

Comment: Не совсем понял желаемое поведение. Если запись и чтение не зависят друг от друга никак, то наверно да, можно было бы их на две асинхронных таски разделить

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, обрашаться к reader._buffer не совсем правильно. Из доков я выяснил, что ридер читает данные до некоего eof, но в моём случае он не содержится в ответе от оборудования. Желаемое поведение - если в буфере нет ничего, то передать управление дальше по циклу. Тут больше вопрос о том, как правильно это реализовать без большого количества говнокода.

Comment: При передаче управления дальше по циклу этот цикл зациклится и будет бесконечно выполнять эти две проверки, тем самым полностью сжирая целое одно ядро процессора по сути на ничегонеделание. Это точно желаемое поведение?

Comment: Отправка команды после появления в очереди и обработка ответа сервера должна пройти почти моментально. Можно добавить asyncio.sleep(0.2) после каждой отправки команды и каждого чтения пачки ответов. Тогда, возможно, это не так загрузит процессор. Вопрос в том, стоит ли пытаться обрабатывать их последовательно в одном цикле, как это начал делать я. Мне интересно, как это правильно реализовать и получить +500 в копилку своих знаний.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как всегда и происходит в подобных ситуациях, пока ждёшь ответ, находишь его сам. Из-за небольшого опыта в программировании я использовал пример из учебника. Там происходит открытие соединения, отправка сообщения, приём ответа и закрытие соединения. Т.к. мне необходимо поддерживать постоянное соединение, я просто зациклил write и read, и всеми способами пытался прекратить блокирующий read по таймауту чтобы сделать следующий write. Правильным выходом из ситуации оказалось разделение приёма и передачи на два асинхронных метода. В итоге соединение с оборудованием поддерживается постоянно, приём и отправка не зависят друг от друга.

```py
async def send_command(writer):
    global cancellation_token

    while not cancellation_token:
        try:
            task_for_send = tasks_queue.get_nowait()
            writer.write(task_for_send.command.encode())
        except Empty:
            pass
        except ConnectionResetError:
            cancellation_token = True
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(0.03)


async def read_answer(reader):
    global cancellation_token

    while not cancellation_token:
        try:
            data = await reader.read(10)
        except ConnectionResetError:
            cancellation_token = True
            break
        print(f'Received {counter}: {data.decode()!r}')


async def tcp_client():
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 50007)
    await asyncio.gather(
        send_command(writer),
        read_answer(reader),
    )
    print('Close the connection')
    writer.close()
    await writer.wait_closed()
    print('Connection is closed')
```